# What's the meaning of McSomebody

Tags: meaning

I wanted to read the book: Milkman.
Here is the first sentence of this book: "The day Somebody McSomebody put a gun to my breast and called me a cat and threatened to shoot me was the same day the milkman died."

What's the meaning of the word "McSomebody" here? I checked many dictionaries but I couldn't find any answers

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Rp226, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: PS "Somebody McSomebody" is a made-up name, like "John Everyman". It means an anonymous, generic or hypothetical person.

Answer (score 1):

Putting 'Mc' on the front of a word is a way of making a connection to the name McDonald's, a ubiquitous fast food restaurant chain and their habbit of naming menu items in that manner: McNuggets, McRib, etc.

That gave us terms like McJob and names like Boaty McBoatface.

So the writer is talking about a generic somebody, an unknown person with a mass-produced impersonality.

Answer (score 0):

The usage when applied to names precedes McDonalds and frequently isn't associated with the chain. Instead, "Mc-" is a common form for making generic names, derived from Scottish and Irish patronyms.

The Oxford English Dictionary lists this as its first entry for "Mc-, comb. form:"

> Prefixed chiefly to nouns to create mock names denoting a person who (or occasionally thing that) is considered an exemplar or personification of the specified class, interest, association, etc.

The first example is from the 1940s:

> 1948, San Francisco Call-Bull. 21 Dec. 20/1:  "Dear McSanta: All I want is a few extra college credits."

So "Somebody McSomebody" is a generic person, perhaps to the point of mocking.